# Java 8: how to use lambda expressions on JoinRowSets?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm developing a feature that will be used among some of my company's products so I can't have product-specific code.

I have the results of 2 queries stored on 2 `JoinRowSet` objects (I do have to use `JoinRowSet` because I have to join other queries' results with these ones later). Then, I need to intersect those 2 `JoinRowSet`s but I don't know what class they "belong" to (I don't know if the query will return People, Contacts, Departments or any other thing). I was told I should use lambda expressions to do this but I'm finding some problems.

I have converted one of the `JoinRowSet` to a Collection (I don't know how to use lambda expressions directly on a `JoinRowSet`), then I'm looping over one of the `JoinRowSet`s and, for each column of this `JoinRowSet`, I want to get the records on the initial Collection that have the same value on that column. But, as I don't know the class of the data, I can't do something like `u.getAge()` because I don't have the property name.

This is my method:

```
public static void testLambdas() throws SQLException {

    ... //set the needed stuff to connect to database and query data 

    JoinRowSet jrs1 = ... //result from query 1
    JoinRowSet jrs2 = ... //result from query 2
    Collection<Row> jrs2Collection = (Collection<Row>) jrs2.getRowSets();//collection to use on lambda expression

    while (jrs1.next()) {

        ResultSetMetaData metadata = jrs1.getMetaData();
        for (int j = 1; j <= metadata.getColumnCount(); j++) {

            String dataType = metadata.getColumnTypeName(j);
            Object colValue = null;

            if (dataType.equals("NUMBER")) {
                colValue = jrs1.getBigDecimal(j);               
            } else if (dataType.equals("VARCHAR2")) {
                colValue = jrs1.getString(j);               
            } else if (dataType.equals("DATE")) {
                colValue = jrs1.getTimestamp(j);
            }
            System.out.println(metadata.getColumnName(j)+ " (" + dataType +"): "+ colValue);            

            Object o = jrs2Collection.stream()
                                     .filter(u -> {
                                         try { 
                                             return (u.getColumnObject(j).equals(colValue));
                                         } catch (Exception e) {
                                             e.printStackTrace();
                                             return false;
                                         }
                                     }) 
                                     .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));

        }
    }
}
```

Please ignore the fact that this use of a lambda expression is inside a while and not being re-used on each iteration. I will take care of that if I can solve the issues I have now.

I had to add the try-catch to the filter because it was returning *Unhandled exception type `SQLException`*. After adding this try-catch, I get a *Local variable `j` defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final* on `u.getColumnObject(j)`.

I have no idea if what I'm doing is the best way to do this or if I'm doing something really wrong (2 of my colleagues have looked at my code and also have no idea how to solve this).

I would appreciate any inputs on this, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not clear what you are trying to do as you are creating collections inside a loop without using them. So I can’t tell you whether there’s a better solution for this.

Regarding the error, the error message is pretty clear. You can’t use a mutable local variable inside a lambda. However, the solution is quite simple: you can assign the content of the mutable variable to an immutable variable:

```
    for (int j = 1; j <= metadata.getColumnCount(); j++) {
        // …
        int currentJ = j;
        Object currentColValue = colValue;
        Object o = jrs2Collection.stream()
          .filter(u -> {
                try { 
                    return (u.getColumnObject(currentJ).equals(currentColValue)); 
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        ) 
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
    }
```

Note that `currentJ` and `currentColValue` are *effectively final* which means you could add a `final` modifier to them without changing the program. It’s a requirement that local variables you use inside a lambda expression are either `final` or *effectively final*.

---

By the way, don’t think about “re-using lambda between iterations”. In most cases, the JRE will take care of reusing the instances created for lambda expressions where possible. And the JDBC operations outweigh any overhead imposed by temporary objects created for lambda expressions anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Problem solved. By the way, what I'm trying to do is just retrieve the records that are on jrs1 and jrs2. I hope this is the right way to go.